# C Preprocessor token merging results in "indefined identifier" error

Tags: c-preprocessor

I've reduced my problem to this snippet:

```
#define AND(a, b) a & b
#define VAL_FOO 0x0f
#define VAL_BAR 0x77
#define DO(v1, v2) AND(VAL_##v1, VAL_##v2)

void main()   // As it should be for XC8
{
    DO(FOO, BAR);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this message:

> undefined identifier "VAL_FOO"
>
> undefined identifier "VAL_BAR"

Both pointing to the line `DO(FOO, BAR);`.

What is wrong with the above? I just can't make sense of it. I've used this sort of code a lot, and I'm stumped why it isn't working in this case. For example, the following works:

```
#define BAZ(a, A, B)                 \
    (AND(c_##a##_d[0], E) == F_##A##_G_##B)
```

And I just can't see the difference! If it makes a difference, I'm compiling C for a PIC16F microcontroller using the XC8 compiler

Edit: I thought it would be worth asking this in the XC8 forum itself, and those in the know are having a discussion on it beyond what my experience would allow:

- [Microchip XC8 Forum: Bug in C Preprocessor macro when merging tokens?](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m938701.aspx)

Comment: Works fine for me if I change the last line to `int main() { printf("%d\n", DO(FOO, BAR)); }`.  Try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Done. it still doesn't work for me

Comment: Well, what you posted now compiles, just with the warning 'statement with no effect' from the expansion of the macro for me.  Would seem to be a bug in the compiler you are using.

Comment: compiling with XC8? Default settings? I don't get the "statement with no effect" - as a general rule it does not filter out such code or even give a warning, it assumes that operations have side effects due to ISRs, hardware changes, and possible manual insertion of assembly

Comment: You can try using the preprocessor from some other compiler before feeding it to the buggy compiler to work around the problem...

Comment: I deleted my answer because for me using gcc 4.7 it works fine both with and without the extra layer of macros. When I posted I had no compiler available. Sorry for the confusion. Agree with @ChrisDodd that cpp tricks like this are almost never defensible in modern C.  Perhaps XC8 has an ancient or buggy cpp?

Comment: Heh. The XC8 manual http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002053F.pdf in section 5.14.2 Preprocessor Directives gives the same trick.

Comment: @gene: The macro indirection is required if you need the arguments being concatenated to be expanded before concatenation. In this case, however, that is not necessary; `FOO` and `BAR` are not themselves macros.

Comment: @Jodes: Please provide more details on the macro expansion which you claim "works". Does it involve constructing the name of a macro using token concatenation, and then expanding that macro? I suspect that is where the problem is in the non-working code.

Comment: I have edit my question, more information is in XC8's forum as per link

Answer (score -1):

If you pass your code through the preprocessor, the error becomes apparent:

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 328 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>" 2

void main()   // As it should be for XC8
{
    VAL_##FOO & VAL_## BAR;
}
```

The whitespace in your token-pasting code is meaningful.  Change it to

```
#define DO(v1,v2) AND(VAL_##v1, VAL_##v2)
```

and the problem is solved.

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. Exactly the same errors. Nice try though